# Did Palpatine have the ability to time travel?

Tags: star-wars, darth-sidious, star-wars-rebels

In *Rebels* final episode, *"Family Reunion - and Farewell"*, we could see that:

> Palpatine managed to create a time traveling portal and offered Ezra a one-way ticket to happy times with his family. All of this, even though the Lothal temple was destroyed in previous episodes.

Was this just an illusion with Sith sorcery to break Ezra, or did Palpatine have the ability to time travel? I suppose he would not squander a one-time ride he could not repeat just to send Ezra away, instead of killing him on the spot.

Comment: FYI: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=jumping%20the%20whale

Comment: I have fixed your wording again. That is an objective edit and should _not_ be rolled back. I will at a later time remove your opinion in the post script. This is not an opinion forum, it is a Q&A site. Your hopes and wishes are irrelevant to this question and have no place in the post. P.S. I guess @BinaryWorrier removed the opinion for me, thanks.

Comment: @Edlothiad: I removed the PS, it invites discussion, and adds nothing to the question. Apologies if my edits stepped on yours.

Comment: Lies and deception, the ways of the Dark Side are. So, my guess is this was just cheap tricks and Dark Side sorcery to lure Ezra...

Comment: Yes, with limits.  He could travel forwards only, at one second experienced per second elapsed.  In other words, the slow, boring way.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to say no, Palpatine alone did not have the ability to time travel. This is based on logical deduction of his actions, events that took place, and the lack of any evidence of time traveling force abilities in Canon.

> Earlier in the 4th season ([episode 13, "A World Between Worlds"](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/A_World_Between_Worlds) ) Palpatine is trying to gain access to the Jedi temple on Lothal and the supposed portal that would allow him to travel through time. If he already had the ability to time travel, why bother excavating an old temple? 
>
>  
> It's implied in the episode that the temple is the source of the portal in which Ezra saw his parents. We also know that he destroyed the temple and took the temple with him when he and the ship jumped to light speed.

This leaves two very possible explanations for what happened.

- It was all an illusion, a ploy by Palpatine to break Ezra and get him to willingly abandon his friends. (As mentioned by Loki in the comments)
- The temple was the source of the time travelling ability, not Palpatine himself, and it was destroyed and lost.

Comment: I doubt possibility number two, i.e. Palpatine returning parts of the temple to Lothal on Thrawn's SD just to send Ezra away. As for option number one, this is possible but it is not clearly explained (how would it work) .

Comment: @rs.29 I agree. And there are instances in legends where such an ability is used. [Force Illusion](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mind_trick/Legends#Force_illusion) basically a subset of the "Mind Trick" ability, allowed to user to project an image into the mind of their target. While this is of course legends, it doesn't seem that far fetched of an ability to bring to canon; especially compared to time travelling.